# Matlab Gamma trasform question. One pixel transform.

Tags: matlab

[image]

How do I do this question?

For a) I believe the value of $c=\frac{1}{255}$ but I'm not sure. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a)

$0 = c \cdot 0^\gamma$

So $c$ doesn't matter (for 0).

$255 = c \cdot 255^\gamma$

$c = \frac{255}{255^\gamma}$

b)

for each $\gamma$:

```
plot(0:255,(255/255.^gamma)*(0:255).^gamma);
```

c)

can be taken from the plots from b)

Comment: So when $\gamma$ is close to 0, it maps quicker? I don't know how to describe it. The graph is steeper.

Comment: The question was, what happens to the image. For gamma very close to zero, all values except for zero values will be mapped to 255. -> Black and white image where only the 0 values from input image are black, rest white. Inverse for large gamma values.